On an ASP.NET website how to handle a GET request for "/data:image/x-icon;,"?
I believe this request is for some kind-of FavIcon, however I haven't seen it prior to six months ago.  Several clients, that are using our site are now making regular requests for this. I'm not sure how to handle it properly with an older ASP.NET (C#) site.  See below what I see in the log, and the bounce into the ErrorPage.
2024-12-17 GET /data:image/x-icon;, - 443 - 99.99.99.99 Mozilla/5.0+(X11;+Linux+x86_64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/124.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - 302 0 0 45
2024-12-17 GET /ErrorPage.aspx aspxerrorpath=/data:image/x-icon;, 443 - 99.99.99.99 Mozilla/5.0+(X11;+Linux+x86_64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/124.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 72

Of course the client likely does not see this part, but still, it would be good to know how to handle the request.  The server is Windows 2016, if that makes a difference, if there is a server-configuration tip that I need.
Edit: More information to share.  So what happens is after a client comes to the site at the end of the log for that person you'll see the above.  But before that they will have a totally different User-Agent:  Like in the example above see this:
Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/131.0.0.0+Safari/537.36

Instead of 'Linux' 4-seconds earlier.


why you are not linking favicon in your HTML
<head> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>


It is indeed there.... That's not it.

These users appear to be unrelated to this type of favicon request, it's a different type.  These users never even looked at href in my "shortcut icon" nor tried /favicon.ico.  And your not really answering the request question.

After checking more exhaustively, I believe this request to be from a bots, scanning emails.  However, what I did to solve at least the error being returned:
in ErrorPage.aspx.cs I added:
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["aspxerrorpath"]))
{
        string aspxerrorpath = Request.QueryString["aspxerrorpath"];
        if (aspxerrorpath == "/data:image/x-icon;,")
            Response.Redirect("favicon.ico");
}

So now I still see an error in my EventViewer, but the request is likely fulfilled.  This is specific for the above case, and it would seem others would be seeing this too, in their logs. If this has to do with SEO searches, or something, I don't know, than I'm happy to make sure the request is filled.  Maybe there is a better way.  Please comment or answer.
